# Why don't the Iranian troops try more extreme measures to stop the departing plane?

Tags: plot-explanation, argo

At the end of [*Argo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1024648/), why don't the Iranian soldiers shoot the wheels ofr the plane in their attempt to stop it at the end of the movie? Why don't they contact the control room to stop it?

Comment: Please read the site [FAQ](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you've posted 3 questions, and 2 of them were closed and deleted.

Comment: Shoot the tires off or fire a Stinger at it! And risk all those lives! Not to mention the catastrophe that would follow if (and oh yes it would) the plane crashed.

Comment: Something which is forgotten here ... this is Iran ... they've done crazier things. As commented below, the movie makes it a little more exciting than it really was. It was talked about in [this](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13784/how-did-the-iranians-realize-the-fraud) thread

Comment: @Paulster2 *"Something which is forgotten here ... this is Iran ... they've done crazier things."* - And you're sure they would crash an international flight and kill dozens of innocents and risk an international scandal and intervention from the international community, and all that just to get some few Americans? C'mon, this is Iran, not an evil fantasy realm full of idiots.

Comment: @ChristianRau ... I wouldn't be too sure of that. I think you need to look at current events to see what kind of "idiots" reside their. Before the religious takeover there (when the Shaw was the ruler) I would have never suggested it. But now? ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because no matter how desperate you are to stop the plane, would you really want to be responsible for shooting at and potentially crashing a full aircraft, fueled for an international flight?  An airline of the national carrier of Switzerland, setting off another international incident, but this time a famously neutral country?

The soldiers do what they can do to attract the pilot's attention.  They do burst into the ATC control tower to get the controllers to communicate with the plane, but its too late.

In reality from my reading of the events, their exit from the country was much less dramatic than shown in the movie.

Comment: Also, in the real story the escape happened before the Army put the pieces together, so the plane was never in any danger of being shot at. Shooting at the plane in the movie would have upset people for it's historical inaccuracy.